# Unable to programmatically read an updated user control property from within MainWindowViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

I've following code in my WPF app.I'm dynamically rendering the user control in MainWindow using  ContentPresenter control on change of SelectedAccountType combobox value.
I enter some value in MyProperty textbox in UI and click on Save button on MainWindow.But I dont see this value in the MainWindowViewModel.cs in the Save method(i.e. on click of Save button).
All my ViewModels extend this abstract class:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
```

What am I missing here please?

Thanks.

Here's my code:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MainViewModel="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel.AccountTypes"
        xmlns:View="clr-namespace:Test.View" x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Test.View.AccountTypes"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Test.View.AccountTypes"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel.AccountTypes"
        Title="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" ResizeMode="CanResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <MainViewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="28" Width="auto" Margin="5,0,0,0">
            <ComboBox Width="360" Margin="1,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AccountTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccountType,
 Mode=TwoWay}" TabIndex="0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:AC1ViewModel}">
                    <Views:AC1View/>
            </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:AC2ViewModel}">
                    <Views:AC2View/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public object CurrentViewModel
{
    get 
        { 
            return m_currentViewModel; 
        }
        set
            {
                m_currentViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");    
            }
        }   


public AccountType SelectedAccountType
{
    get
    {
        return m_selectedSearchAccountType;
    }
    set
    {
        m_selectedSearchAccountType = value;
            if (SelectedAccountType.Code == "AC1")
        {
            CurrentViewModel  = new AC1ViewModel();
        }
        else if (SelectedAccountType.Code == "AC2")
        {
            CurrentViewModel  = new AC2ViewModel();
        }
    }
}

public void Save()
{
        Type sourceType = CurrentViewModel.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] sourcePI = sourceType.GetProperties();

        Type destinationType = securityDetails.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] destinationPI = destinationType.GetProperties();

        string propertyName = string.Empty;
        object propertyValue = null;

        foreach (var pinfo in sourcePI)
        {
            propertyName = pinfo.Name.Trim();
            propertyValue = pinfo.GetValue(CurrentViewModel)
        }
}
```

AC1View.xaml:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="1,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" TabIndex="1" Text="{Binding MyProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

AC1ViewModel.cs

```
public class AC1ViewModel
{
    private string m_myProperty = "";
    public AC1ViewModel()
    {

    }


    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return m_myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            m_myProperty = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: By "SaveButtonCommand method", I presume you mean `Save()`? Is `MyProperty` being enumerated in that loop?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.Also, yes, MyProperty is being enumerated in that loop

Comment: Are the bindings working correctly? If you debug them, can you check that your properties are being set?

Comment: Is `SelectedAccountType` possibly changing in the interim? That would result in a new object in CurrentViewModel. That would be easy to check with a breakpoint in the setter. But first, per @Forlani, I'd put a breakpoint in the `MyProperty` setter in AC1ViewModel

Comment: Yes, when am in debug mode, I can see that MyProperty is being set with the new value.Its just that I dont see the updated value while reading it in Save method in MainViewModel.Thanks.

Comment: Your reflection code looks fine to me. If that's not broken, then either you've got two different instances in CurrentViewModel, or you're setting that property value to an empty string somewhere in between. Do you have any other code that touches any of this stuff?

Comment: Try two-way binding mode in `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">`.  I'm getting a weird feeling that somehow your binding is out of sync.

Comment: Thanks B.K. and all.I tried the followinng but no luck:<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me as it is. There must be something you didn't include in the question.

Comment: (caveat: I added a semicolon after `pinfo.GetValue(CurrentViewModel)`; but if your code compiles, you clearly did the same)

Comment: Ed, you are spot on.I was referencing AC1ViewModel class in my user control as well and that was causing to return a new instance of that class in MainViewModel.Thanks for your help.Appreciated!